# how to extract members of a List sitting inside 2 by 2 table?

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a two-by-two table. Each element of the table is a four-member list:

```
   {{{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.}, {1., "UG", 0.0140148, 0.}, {1., "PT", 
   0.00404167, 0.850746}, {0.91578, "PT", 0.00279461, 0.925425}, {0, 
   "UB", 0.0025, 1.}}, {{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.}, {1., "PT", 
   0.025125, 0.919355}, {0.829708, "PT", 0.0230656, 0.953219}, {0, 
   "UB", 0.0225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0225, 1.}}, {{1., "PT", 0.0660417, 
   0.934426}, {0.741657, "PT", 0.063207, 0.961743}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 
   1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}}, {{0.666667, 
   "CT", 0.123241, 0.968254}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225,
    1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}}, {{0, "UB", 
   0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, 
   "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}}}
```

[image]
how can I generate four tables out of this table? For example, I want my first table just include the first member of 4-member lists (e.g., {{1,1,1,0.9157,0},....}) and so forth.

Comment: your data is not entered correctly. it is chopped off.

Answer (score 5):

```
MatrixForm@
 (data = {{{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.}, {1., "UG", 0.0140148, 0.},
     {1., "PT", 0.00404167, 0.850746}, {0.91578, "PT", 0.00279461, 0.925425},
     {0, "UB", 0.0025, 1.}}, {{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.},
     {1., "PT", 0.025125, 0.919355}, {0.829708, "PT", 0.0230656, 0.953219},
     {0, "UB", 0.0225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0225, 1.}},
    {{1., "PT", 0.0660417, 0.934426}, {0.741657, "PT", 0.063207, 0.961743},
     {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}},
    {{0.666667, "CT", 0.123241, 0.968254}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.},
     {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}},
    {{0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.},
     {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}}})

tables = data[[All, All, 1]]
```

> {{1., 1., 1., 0.91578, 0}, {1., 1., 0.829708, 0, 0}, {1., 0.741657, 0,
> 0, 0}, {0.666667, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0}}

See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html

Comment: Thanks! Why do we need the MatrixForm? The "data" code line worked perfectly. I still don't understand the logic of All, All!

Comment: `MatrixForm` is just to make the output look the same as your screenshot.  It doesn't affect the content of `data`.  `data[[All, All, 1]]` is equivalent to `Part[data, All, All, 1]` i.e. take the 1st part of All the level 2 parts of All the level 1 parts.  For instance 0.91578 is in the 1st part of the 4th part of the 1st part: `data[[1, 4, 1]]`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, Chris. Super helpful

Answer (score 3):

Look up [`Transpose`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Transpose.html):

```
data = {{{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.}, {1., "UG", 0.0140148, 0.}, {1., "PT", 0.00404167, 0.850746}, {0.91578, "PT", 0.00279461, 0.925425}, {0, "UB", 0.0025, 1.}},
        {{1., "UG", 0.0525565, 0.}, {1., "PT", 0.025125, 0.919355}, {0.829708, "PT", 0.0230656, 0.953219}, {0, "UB", 0.0225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0225, 1.}},
        {{1., "PT", 0.0660417, 0.934426}, {0.741657, "PT", 0.063207, 0.961743}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.0625, 1.}},
        {{0.666667, "CT", 0.123241, 0.968254}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.1225, 1.}},
        {{0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}, {0, "UB", 0.2025, 1.}}};

data2 = Transpose[data, {2, 3, 1}];
MatrixForm /@ data2
```

$$
\left\{\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 1. & 1. & 1. & 0.91578 & 0 \\
 1. & 1. & 0.829708 & 0 & 0 \\
 1. & 0.741657 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0.666667 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 \text{UG} & \text{UG} & \text{PT} & \text{PT} & \text{UB} \\
 \text{UG} & \text{PT} & \text{PT} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} \\
 \text{PT} & \text{PT} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} \\
 \text{CT} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} \\
 \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} & \text{UB} \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0.0525565 & 0.0140148 & 0.00404167 & 0.00279461 & 0.0025 \\
 0.0525565 & 0.025125 & 0.0230656 & 0.0225 & 0.0225 \\
 0.0660417 & 0.063207 & 0.0625 & 0.0625 & 0.0625 \\
 0.123241 & 0.1225 & 0.1225 & 0.1225 & 0.1225 \\
 0.2025 & 0.2025 & 0.2025 & 0.2025 & 0.2025 \\
\end{array}
\right),\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 0. & 0. & 0.850746 & 0.925425 & 1. \\
 0. & 0.919355 & 0.953219 & 1. & 1. \\
 0.934426 & 0.961743 & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 0.968254 & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. & 1. \\
\end{array}
\right)\right\}
$$
For example, `data2[[1]]` is now the first $5\times5$ matrix, etc.